# How to come out of "Start a task process" action in Sharepoint Designer if no action has been taken

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site, sharepoint-designer-workflow

As per my requirement, after 7 days of Task creation if the action has not been taken, then task automatically approved.

My problem is with in "start a task process" action how it understand that the task response is not yet received. There is no way to add any condition within this action. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a drop down field or a check box field in the form that shows that a task has been picked/ completed. For example define a field called Task Status - whenever the user changes this fields value to completed you can check this value to see if the "Task response" was received.

Please see example below:-
[image]